# How to make a component that adds an event handler to each control in a Form?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I was just creating a Windows form that uses a `ToolTip` control and it occurred to me that this component provides design time properties for every other control on the form.

I know that for properties you can simply implement the `IExtender` interface but can this be extended to events? If so how to do it?

Comment: can you give a concrete example of what you are after?

Comment: Well, you could use a custom designer that would behave in a similar way, while keeping it a property. The question is *why*. Why do you want to add an event handler to your control, associated with another control in the designer? Don't you just want to have the event on your control, while the other controls will just have a setting whether to participate in that event handling or not?

Comment: Not an option.  The [ProvideProperty] attribute specifies what properties are added by the extender, there is no equivalent [ProvideEvent] attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use recursively function to add events hanlder to all controls even if they are nested inside of a container like grids or panels

Normaly I use this function for a lot of things
Even if I want to add a custom backgroundcolor when got focus/leave.

```
private void addEventhandler(Control Parent) {

    if (Parent.Controls.Count > 0) {
        //===>If the curren control is a container!
        foreach(Control iChild in Parent.Controls) {
            addEventhandler(iChild);//Call it self
        }
    } else {//Individual control
        //===>TODO: Add here all your events handler to Parent variable.

        Parent.Click += new EvenHandler(delegate(object sender,object e){
                                            MessageBox.Show("Hello");
                                            });

        //==>If you whant to filter by control type you can do this
        if(Parent is TextBox){
            ((TextBox)Parent).Text = "Hi! XD";
        }
    }
}
```

Implement this code like this

```
addEventhandler(this);//If you want to add the events handler to all controls in your form

addEventhandler(myGridControl);//To specific grid
```